# SQL datetimeoffset to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datetime column in a table which is in **GMT**.
I'm trying to convert this using the `AT TIME ZONE` function to **PST**.  I can do this but I need the result to be as `datetime` only not with the `datetimeoffset`.

```
SELECT MyTableMyDateColumn AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS 'OrderDate' 
FROM MyTable;
```

I've tried `format` as below as well:

```
SELECT FORMAT(MyTableMyDateColumn , 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss') at TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time' at TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'
FROM MyTable
```

Appreciate all pointers and suggestions

Comment: Which dbms are you using? FORMAT is a product specific function.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific SA Standard Time'

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. `PST` isn't a timezone name anyway, it's an ambiguous shorthand (Pakistan Standard Time? Poland Summer Time?). Use a proper timezone name

Comment: People don't use GMT, they use UTC. The term "GMT" is just a historical artefact now.

Comment: BTW, `datetimeoffset(n)` is parametersized - you haven't said if you're using `datetimeoffset(1)` or `datetimeoffset(7)`.

Comment: @Charlieface That's _Greenwich mean time_ (uncapitalized), [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time#:~:text=without%20capitalisation).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos PST stands for `Pacific Standard Time` and `Pitcairn Standard Time`, both have the same offset from UTC (-8). Pakistan Standard Time is PKT (UTC +5). Poland is using CET (Central European Time) or CEST (Central European Summer Time) in summer.  
https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/

Comment: Use `select * from sys.time_zone_info` to find the valid timezone names. There's `UTC`, `GMT Standard Time` and `Greenwich Standard Time`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled based on which country's conventions? That's my point - these acronyms are ambiguous and not standardized. Just look for timezone-related questions from Indian developers asking for `IST`. In fact, the link you posted shows that `IST` is India, Israel and India Standard time.

Comment: The de-facto timezone name standard is the IANA timezone database, with names like `America/Los_Angeles` and `Europe/Berlin`. Unfortunately, SQL Server uses Windows timezone names which aren't used by anyone outside Windows.

Comment: I agree they aren't unique identifiers, I was just nitpicking, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple cast to datetime should do the trick.

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
  MyTableMyDateColumn DateTime
);

INSERT INTO MyTable (MyTableMyDateColumn) VALUES 
(GETUTCDATE()), 
(GETDATE());
```

The query:

```
SELECT MyTableMyDateColumn,
       MyTableMyDateColumn AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time' As GMT, 
       MyTableMyDateColumn AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS PST,
       -- doing "at time zone" twice is redundant, as you can see in the results
       MyTableMyDateColumn AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS OrderDate, 
       CAST (MyTableMyDateColumn AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' As DATETIME) As PSTDateTime
FROM MyTable;
```

Results:

| MyTableMyDateColumn | GMT | PST | OrderDate | PSTDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-06 10:07:39.057 | 2023-12-06 10:07:39.057 +00:00 | 2023-12-06 10:07:39.057 -08:00 | 2023-12-06 02:07:39.057 -08:00 | 2023-12-06 10:07:39.057 |
| 2023-12-06 10:07:39.057 | 2023-12-06 10:07:39.057 +00:00 | 2023-12-06 10:07:39.057 -08:00 | 2023-12-06 02:07:39.057 -08:00 | 2023-12-06 10:07:39.057 |

See a live demo on [<kbd>db<>fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/y3TaE1_H)

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your kind assistance and patience.  Working as required.

Comment: Glad to help :-)